# Is there a limit on how slow a function can grow with restrictions that can be extended to complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Is there a limit on how slow a function $h$ can grow while being a Differentiable real and continuous function where all real value inputs have greater output than $0$ ,$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} h(x) = 0$, and the $h(x)$ is always increasing and increases without bound, and if extended through analytical continuation to the complex numbers still Differentiable and Continuous with no holes.

here is how I'm going to measure how slow a function grows

1. let $f$ be a function we are trying to measure the slowness of, then we find a function $g$ which must take any real number values, where these equation are true $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(f(g(x))-f(x)) = 1$$
   $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(f(g(x))-f(x))^{x} = 1 $$
2. if there is a $f_1$ and $f_2$ and a $g$ where $f_1$ ang $g$ has the property, and $f_2$ and $g$ also has that property then they are the measured to grow at the same speed.
3. for a $f_1$ and $f_2$ if $O(g_1) > O(g_2)$ and there isn't another $g_1$ and $g_2$ where $O(g_1) \le O(g_2)$ then $f_1$ considered slower than $f_2$

I find no good reason that there would be a limit on how slow a function with these restrictions can go, but I am having trouble finding good ones

examle: I tried $\ln(x)$ which has a $g(x) = ex$ ,meaning you have to multiply your input about e times in order to increase the output about $1$, in $\ln(x)$ case exactly $1$ but the function does not except values for all real numbers, it has negitive number outputs, and if you try to extand it to the complex numbers you don't get a function, but a multi-function where one input can have many outputs.

There is a limit on how a slow function can be if there is a large enough $g(x)$ and no other $g$ grows faster than $g(x)$ where there is no $f(x)$ that follows $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(f(g(x))-f(x)) = 1$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(f(g(x))-f(x))^{x} = 1 $$
note $g(x)$ does not need to be differentiable or continuous but it must never decrease and must allow all real number as inputs.

a side question is there a known function $f$ that follows the rules where $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(f(x^x)-f(x)) = 1$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(f(x^x)-f(x))^{x} = 1$$

if there is a limit how do we prove it, and if not how would we prove it?

Comment: I just want to comment that your more precise definition certainly violates the "slowest growing" in the title. Obviously, lots of functions grow orders of magnitude more slowly than $\ln x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes but $\ln(x)$ doesn't even follow my requirements, it isn't always positive the limit as x goes to negitive infintity isn't zero, and it does output values for all real numbers, so ln(x) isn't even a valid function, because ln(x) isn't a differantable or continuoues function for all real values, and can not be extanded nicely to complex numbers anyway.

Comment: Your complaint about negative $x$ can be resolved by patching functions together continuously or smoothly. I haven't thought about it carefully, but I suspect that extending to $\Bbb C$ will be impossible.

Comment: there is a result noted on this site (references, sketch proof) that shows that for any $h(x)>0$ continuous on the real axis, there is an entire function $g$ (which can be taken to have no complex zeroes either) real on the reals st $0<g(x)<h(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ so there is no "lowest" order of growth